# pg_restore | Restore all schema

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

Currently I have a database dump, for some testing purpose sometimes i need to import the production DB locally.

For an unknown reason when i run `$ pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -U 'root' --host=localhost --dbname=db_local ./db_prod.dump` schema are not created. Instead i have those logs.

> postgres_1  | 2022-02-01 11:48:07.402 UTC [103] ERROR:  schema "abuse" does not exist
>
> postgres_1  | 2022-02-01 11:48:07.402 UTC [103] STATEMENT:  DROP
> SCHEMA abuse;

So currently i'm stuck, 'cause i really don't know and don't find any solution for this issue.

Comment: From here [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) add `--if-exists` to the command. Though the `ERROR` should not prevent the creation of the object. Are there other `FATAL` errors in the logs?

Comment: Actually I don't think  it was ever broken, all `--if-exists` does is eliminate the 'does not exist' error messages. The objects themselves will still be created.

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by the `--clean` option: `pg_restore` tries to drop the object before creating it.

Either ignore the harmless error message or use the `--if-exists` option to suppress it.